# Connecting Airflow Operator with Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow

I am running an GKE Airflow Operator from market place and I have not idea as how to store my dags in google cloud bucket while deploying them in containers.

I tried the following, but it's not reflecting on the bucket

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: airflow.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: AirflowCluster
metadata:
  name: airflow-cluster
spec:
  executor: Celery
  config:
    airflow:
      AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL: 30 # default is 300s
  redis:
    operator: False
  scheduler:
    version: "1.10.0rc2"
  ui:
    replicas: 1
  worker:
    replicas: 2
  dags:
    subdir: "/dags"
    gcs:
      bucket: "gs://airflowdags"
  airflowbase:
    name: airflow-base
EOF
```